# How to pass tooltip and progress-bar styling to Rshiny app with css?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying understand and build an Rshiny app based on tutorial examples.

(1) Column Rendering  (http://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html)

(2) Progress bar (http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html)

(3) Style your app with CSS (http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html)

I am able to style the App appearance by passing 
 `shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",.........))` And it works vey well in changing the appearance of tables, input boxes, buttons etc.

However, in-spite of changing the parameters in bootstrap.css file for 
Tooltip and  Progress bar,  does not have any effect on the app. For, instance when I code the following column rendering using java script. A tooltip appears when I scroll on the column ( as explained in the tutorial), but when I change the parameters in bootstrap.css file for the tooltip font-size and font etc. It does not have any effect. Is there a specific way to let rshiny understand that I have a CSS file with tooltip and progress bar styling ? or the styling options are limited ?
Thank you

```
columnDefs = list(list(targets  = 6,
                       render   = JS(
                       "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
                       "return type === 'display' && data.length > 100 ?",
                       "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' +
                       data.substr(0, 100) + '...</span>' : data;", "}"))),
```